# how to stop validation control when a cell of gridview become clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

i have a gridview and some text boxes with required field validator and buttons all inside of a table and table is inside of update panel. 
I am displying data in textboxes on the click of a specific record of gridview and all was working fine but after applying some validation to text boxeses(e.g., required fied validator) as i click to the gridview validation get runs and the gridview record is not showing to me becuase of validation.
so how can i show data??

ongridview selected index change event

```
txtfirsName.Text= gvData.SelectedRow.cells[1].Text;
```

and i think above code not a problem but i have posted .real concern with validation

Comment: Can you post your code...

Comment: @vignesh which code??

Comment: sorry design code not available. i will post it tomrrow becuase code in office